Draw bifurcation diagram for Van der Pol oscillator
I'm trying to study graphically the dynamics of the Van der Pol oscillator:
$\dot x(t) = -\frac{x(t)^3}{3}+x(t)+y(t)$
$\dot y(t) = \epsilon(\mu-x(t))$
I've managed to obtained the phase diagram and the trajectories, but I wasn't able to find a way to plot the bifurcation diagram in the ($\mu$,x) plane.
This is the code I've written so far:
(*Van der Pol oscillator*)
ϵ = .1;
sys = {
   x'[t] == - x[t]^3/3 + x[t] + y[t],
   y'[t] == ϵ (μ - x[t]),
   x[0] == .5, y[0] == .5};
{xsol, ysol} = {x, y} /. 
   ParametricNDSolve[sys, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1000}, {μ}];

Manipulate[
 Row[{
   ParametricPlot[{xsol[μ][t], ysol[μ][t]}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
    PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> 400],
   Plot[{ysol[μ][t]}, {t, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> Full, 
    ImageSize -> 400]}],
 {μ, -1.5, 1.5}, Dynamic[μ]]

Manipulate[
 Show[
  VectorPlot[{- x^3/3 + x + y, ϵ (μ - x)}, {x, -2.5, 
    2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}],
  ParametricPlot[{xsol[μ][t], ysol[μ][t]}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
   PlotStyle -> Black],
  ContourPlot[- x^3/3 + x + y == 0, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Green, Thick}]],
 {μ, -1.5, 1.5}, Dynamic[μ]]

I've looked for previous answers but I wasn't able to found anything useful.
Does someone has any idea?

This equation system is not similar to the van der Pol oscillator described on  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator . How it connects to van der Pol?

If you look at the trajectories or the phase plane of the system it is the same that the one of the Van der Pol oscillator. I don't know the exact transformation in order to pass from one to another though, but it was gives as this to me.

So the question is about a given system of equation, not about van der Pol, since for van der Pol there are many papers including this one  https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.72.026203

To plot bifurcation diagram for this system we use standard approach described here. First we define fixed points
rhs = {-x^3/3 + x + y, \[Epsilon]  (\[Mu] - x)};

fixpt = {x, y} /. Solve[rhs == 0, {x, y}]

Out[]= {{\[Mu], 1/3 \[Mu] (-3 + \[Mu]^2)}}

Second, we compute eigenvalues of a linear system
lin = 
 Series[rhs, Sequence @@ Transpose[{{x, y}, fixpt[[1]], {1, 1}}]] // 
  Normal;

 jm = D[lin, {{x, y}}];

 ev = Eigenvalues[jm] // N

Out[]= {0.5  (1. - 1. \[Mu]^2 - 
    1.  Sqrt[1. - 4. \[Epsilon] - 2. \[Mu]^2 + \[Mu]^4]), 
 0.5  (1. - 1. \[Mu]^2 + Sqrt[
    1. - 4. \[Epsilon] - 2. \[Mu]^2 + \[Mu]^4])} 

Finally we plot real and imaginary part of eigenvalues as a function of parameters as follows
Table[{Plot[Evaluate[Re[ev]], {\[Mu], -2, 2}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"\[Epsilon] = ", \[Epsilon]}]], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Im[ev]], {\[Mu], -2, 2}]}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1, .1}]


It could be interesting to plot bifurcation diagram to see transition from $\epsilon =0.1$ to $\epsilon =0.2$, we have, for example
 bifur = Compile[{{\[Epsilon], _Real}, {\[Mu], _Real}}, ({\[Epsilon], \
#[[1]], #[[2]]} &) /@ 
    Union[Drop[
      NestList[{(-#[[1]]^3)/3 + #[[1]] + #[[
           2]], \[Epsilon] (\[Mu] - #[[1]])} &, {.5, .5}, 300], 100]]];


list = Module[{\[Mu] = 0.01}, 
   lst = Flatten[
     Table[bifur[\[Epsilon], \[Mu]], {\[Epsilon], .1, .2, .0001}], 1];
    lst];


var = {x, y}; Table[
 ListPlot[Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, j + 1]]}],
    PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[.001],
  FrameLabel -> {\[Epsilon] , var[[j]]},
   ImageSize -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True], {j, 2}] 


Also transition from $\epsilon=0$,to $\epsilon =0.1$ at $\mu<0$ shows chaotic behaver
list = Module[{\[Mu] = -.1}, 
   lst = Flatten[
     Table[bifur[\[Epsilon], \[Mu]], {\[Epsilon], .0001, .1, .0001}], 
     1]; lst];


var = {x, y}; Table[
 ListPlot[Transpose[{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, j + 1]]}],
    PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[.001],
  FrameLabel -> {\[Epsilon] , var[[j]]},
   ImageSize -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True], {j, 2}] 



Thank you, this was really useful!

@Gabri_BH You are welcome!
